# Is it possible to publish an app in google play in such a way that the description depends on the browser/Android language?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish an app in Google play and I want to make sure that the description depends on the browser language or Android language.

I want to make sure that people with a browser or Android implementation in Dutch automatically get the description in Dutch and other people get the description in English. Is this possible? It would nice as well if my application could be found both when searching on Dutch terms and on English terms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You just need to add more languages to your google play app entry, by using "Manage translations". You can also set what language it all fall back when user language is not directly supported (so it does not have to be English).

[image: Manage translations]

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract all labels and messages and store them in resource files.

Then on loading the application you can get current language in android device using **Local**.

and using the current language you can load messages and labels in appropriate language.

visit this : [Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)